# Angular Js trying to dynamically change modal text from main button call back and not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implement a angular js pop up with the text will dynamically changed based on a callback from a button.

So basically the user will press a button I will check for a certain error condition, and if there is an error pop up a dialog with the error code.
The problem is that the text in pop up only ever displays the text I have when I initialize the variable. If I try to change from my button callback it does not change the text.

There is a lot of code so I will post the different parts that matter.

Here is my error.html which my pop up

```
  <div ng-controller='datarec'>

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">Rec Error</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body" >

    <div >{{ recError }} </div>

  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">Ok</button>

</div>
```

Here is my controller for the pop up

```
testApp.controller('recordErrorCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close(true);
  };

});
```

Here is my main app javascript file

```
    testApp.controller('datarec', ['$scope',


  function ($scope) {



    $scope.recError  = "No error yet";  // init to this,which works


....

    $scope.sendRecMessage = function() {
      $scope.recordingError = " Init 2";  // This I never see in pop up
       // call my popup 
       popup (errorCtrler);
    }
```

So basically when I pop up the error it will never see the "Init 2", it will just stay at the original No error yet

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for you current situation.  I can alter it to give you a working solution.

Comment: "sendRecMessage"might need to be within a factory and be injected into the controller.

Comment: Sorry I cant' copy the entire code to a file since there are portions which I am not allowed to share due to classification,etc.

Comment: shouldn't `$scope.recordingError` be `$scope.recError` because that is what you're using in your view? Looks like you never update the text that is sent shown in the popup...

Comment: I fixed that typo when I was copying things, I will try the factory and inject

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Angular UI Bootstrap, and it could be that you are not passing in the correct scope or parameters. Try using resolve to send the parameter to the popup.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      controller: 'recordErrorCtrl',
      resolve: {
        recError: function () {
          return $scope.recError;
        }
      }
    });
```

You also have ng-controller='datarec' in your html. This might need to be removed so that the proper controller ('recordErrorCtrl') is taken into consideration.

Comment: where should the above code go and how would it be invoked

Comment: Well at some point you must have some code to open the modal, right? That's where the resolve should be. Unless you are using a different module altogether...